# How do I run extra commands when a program in supervisor (re)starts?

Tags: supervisord

How do I run extra commands when a program in supervisor starts/restarts?

Particularly, In this case, I need to do a chmod on a file that the running process creates (socket file).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use the [Event Listener](http://supervisord.org/events.html). Supervisor provides a way for a specially written program (which it runs as a subprocess) called an “event listener” to subscribe to “event notifications”. When you receive the specific event, you can do whatever you want to do.

In you condition, you can listen the event which indicates that YOU_PROGRAM has been started/stopped, and then call the command to chmod the file.